# Computing dimension of the splitting field.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Find the splitting field $E$ of $f(x)=x^3+1$ over $F=
\mathbb{Z_2}$ and compute $[E:F]$.

First we find the roots of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+1$
$f(x)=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)=0$ gives $x=-1, \frac{1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2} $
Hence, $E=F(-1, \frac{1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2})=F(\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2})$
since $[-1]=[1] \in F $ and $\frac{1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}=1+\frac{1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}$
Note that $x^2-x+1$ is irreducible in $F$ since there are only two linear factors $x, x+1$ in $F$.
Then $[E:F]=[F(\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}): F]$=2

Do you think my argument is correct?

Comment: No, it's degree $2$. $F[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^2-x+1$ is already Galois.

Comment: You have a typo in the title of your question, which is the first thing you should check for typos before posting a question.

Comment: oh i edited it. i didn't consider 1 in my linear equation and actually $1, \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}, \frac{1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: You cannot divide by $2$ in $\mathbb Z_2$. Also $i$ in a field of characteristic $2$ does not mean anything. And since $3=1$, $\sqrt{3}$ is a complicated way of writing $1$.

Comment: sorry I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did well until the first descomposition:
$$f(x)=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
or, since $1=-1$ in this field:
$$f(x)=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Now, since the characteristic of $F$ is $2$ you can not apply the formula for solving second degree equations.

Observe instead that $0$ and $1$ are not roots of $x^2+x+1$, so every root of this polynomial is outside $F$. Since they are roots of a second degree equation, this polynomial is the minimum polynomial over $F$ of these roots. The belong to a normal extension of degree $2$, that is, $E=\Bbb F_4$.

This field is the only field (up to iso) with $4$ elements.

$$\Bbb F_4=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1\}$$

where $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$.

Note that also $(\alpha+1)^2+(\alpha+1)+1=\alpha^2+2\alpha+1+\alpha+1+1=\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$

Comment: The final check is not necessary: if $\beta$ is the second root, then $\alpha+\beta=1$ by Viète’s relations. By the way, $\beta=\alpha^{-1}$, again by Viète.